# Converting a SOAP request to a HTTP 200 return on wsO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a instance where I need to implement a proxy service that takes a SOAP message, forwards it to an internal system (SOAP) and returns a HTTP 200 response to the original server.
Basically the response should be completely void of any soap detail (there's technically no output message in the WSDL that I have to implement).
Here's what I have so far (which simply takes the request & echos it back as the response):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="ExampleHttp200Return"
   transports="http"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full" separator=", - inSequence: received - "/>
         <header name="To" action="remove"/>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="SC_ACCEPTED" value="false" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="HTTP_SC" value="200" scope="axis2"/>
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send back an empty response, you can add that before send mediator :

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="text/plain"/>
<enrich>
    <source type="inline">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
               <text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"/>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </source>
    <target type="envelope"/>
</enrich>
```

Comment: But that returns an empty soap envelope.  I want it to return only an HTTP  200 (no soap at all).

Comment: That does it.  I'm not entirely sure how it totally drops the soap envelope that it appears to create, but it does.  Thanks!!

Comment: messageType="text/plain" tell the ESB to send back a plain text message. The content of this message is the value of the node named "text" inside the soap body : here, there is no value...